# Metal lathe tool post on a wood lathe

Tags: lathe, woodturning

I’ve been wanting to try and use a chisel holder tool post like on a metal lathe on a wood lathe for a while now, I’ve looked a bit online but didn’t find any tool holders that are made for wood lathes. Does anyone know maybe where I should look? Do you know if maybe a metal lathe tool holder would work? I joined this community right when I found a thread on here about the idea, after searching google for weeks lol so any guidance would be greatly appreciated ❤️ I’m relatively new at woodturning, but an avid woodworker for about 6 years

Comment: Duplicators for wood lathes use something similar like Grizzly T27313 - Copy Attachment there are many others. I have used a metal lathe to turn wooden parts several times. hope this helps.

Comment: Wood cuts very differently than does metal. You might be able to rough out a turned piece, but I think you'd end up with so much tear out that it wouldn't be worthwhile.